# The Property method can only be used with primitive or complex properties. Use the Reference or Collection method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

> The property 'Tags' on type 'Post' is not a primitive or complex property. The Property method can only be used with primitive or complex properties. Use the Reference or Collection method.

I am using this code snippets for update a post text and related tags:

```
            var tags = TagConverter.FetchTags(postText);
            var newTags = tags.Select(t => t.Title);
            var savedTags = _db.Tags.Where(t => newTags.Contains(t.Title)).ToList();
            var notSavedTags = tags.Where(t => savedTags.All(st => st.Title != t.Title)).ToList();
            var insertedTags = _db.Tags.AddRange(notSavedTags).ToList();
            insertedTags.AddRange(savedTags);
            _db.SaveChanges();


            var updatedPost = post;
            updatedPost.Title = postText;
            updatedPost.Tags = insertedTags;
            _db.Posts.Attach(updatedPost);
            var entry = _db.Entry(updatedPost);
            entry.Property(e => e.Title).IsModified = true;
            entry.Property(e => e.Tags).IsModified = true;


            _db.SaveChanges();
```

How to update tags?

Comment: Where does `post` come from? And why do you save the tags separately by a `SaveChanges` call? And do they have a many-to-many relationship?

Answer (score 0):

Setting `IsModified` works for single entity, not for a collection. This is why this line doesn't work:

```
entry.Property(e => e.Tags).IsModified = true;
```

As you already attached all tags to context, you need to manually compare and update `updatedPost.Tags` collection with `insertedTags`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think it should work just fine with only one call to  `_db.SaveChanges();`.

You get an Exception because of this line, just remove it:

```
entry.Property(e => e.Tags).IsModified = true;
```

Also, I would put 
`_db.Posts.Attach(updatedPost);` 
before `updatedPost.Tags = insertedTags;`. 
After these changes, your code most likely should work.

Another option is to use ChangeRelationshipState() method. Take a look at it in the code below. You can also check out this [EF Relationships and Navigation Properties doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx) for more info (see "Creating and Modifying Relationships" section).

I changed only second part of your code and also added "using":

```
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

var tags = TagConverter.FetchTags(postText);
var newTags = tags.Select(t => t.Title);
var savedTags = _db.Tags.Where(t => newTags.Contains(t.Title)).ToList();
var notSavedTags = tags.Where(t => savedTags.All(st => st.Title != t.Title)).ToList();
var insertedTags = _db.Tags.AddRange(notSavedTags).ToList();
insertedTags.AddRange(savedTags);
_db.SaveChanges();


var updatedPost = post();
_db.Posts.Attach(updatedPost);
updatedPost.Title = postText;

var entry = _db.Entry(updatedPost);
entry.Property(e => e.Title).IsModified = true;

foreach (var tag in insertedTags)
{
   ((IObjectContextAdapter)DbContext).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.
   ChangeRelationshipState(updatedPost, tag, e => e.Tags, EntityState.Added);
} 

_db.SaveChanges();
```